# How to send two different id's from onclick function to a resource route controller

Tags: laravel-4

{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('secureadmin.services.destroy', $est->id), 'onSubmit'=>'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this ...?")','id'=>'deleteform'.$est->establishment_id, 'style'=>'display: inline')) }}
                        establishment_id}}').submit()">
                        {{ Form::close() }}
                        @endif

This is my controller code, when i click on delete i want to send two different id's to the controller. Please help how to pass two id's in onclick function , i am using resource route and laravel version 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the destroy method created in the resource controller, you have to create another function in your existing controller for deleting multiple values and send your ids through post to that function

1. Create the form with method = post and Laravel _method field as
   DELETE
2. Then send your ids from that form to the newly built function using some hidden input form element.
3. Get these ids in the the function through Request variable and do
   the deleting

Comment: ok, so you saying we cannot send two id's in resource controller, we need to create another controller for that..

Comment: You do not need to make another controller, just another function in that controller, i have edited the answer.

Comment: kindly up vote it if it is helpful and mark it as answered if it solves your problem